# BackgridJs - How to show an object in grid

Tags: backbone.js, backgrid

I want to show a grid for this document (model):

```
{
    id: "53f7ba4b30d2317912fc8004",
    title: "Hellow world",
    on_slideshow: false,
    country: {
        name: "United state",
        country_code: "US"
    }
    tags: [
        {
            name: "backbonejs"
            object_id: "72691"
        },
        {
            name: "backgrid"
            object_id: "72692"
        }
    ]
}
```

in my js file ..

```
var grid = new Backgrid.Grid({
    columns: [{
        name: "title",
        label: "Title",
        cell: "string"
    },
    {
        name: "country",
        label: "Country",
        cell: "string"
    },
    {
        name: "on_slideshow",
        label: "Slide",
        cell: "boolean"
    },
    {
        name: "tags",
        label: "Tags",
        cell: "string"
    },
    {
        name: "pub_date",
        label: "Publiched",
        cell: "string"
    }],
  collection: articles
}).render();
```

Tags show as [object Object],[object Object] and country didn't show at all.

How can I show them properly, Tags' name and country list ?

Answer (score 0):

Backgrid is designed to create tables for `Collection`s with `Model`s whose data is 1-level deep, but your `Model` has data two-levels deep.  You *could* opt to use custom formatters, or override the `render` method of your `Column`'s `Cell`s, but probably the simplest solution is just to "flatten" your model a bit to make it easy for Backgrid to digest.

For example:

```
var Article = Backbone.Model.extend({
    flatten: function() {
        var flatVersion = this.toJSON();
        flatVersion.country = this.get('country').name;
        flatVersion.tags = this.get('tags').join(', ');
        return new Backbone.Model(flatVersion);
    }
});
```

and then add a similar flatten method to your `Collection`:

```
var Articles = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    flatten: function() {
        return this.invoke('flatten');
    }
});
```

and then finally pass the flattened version to Backgrid:

```
var grid = new Backgrid.Grid({
    ...
    collection: articles.flatten()
});
```

Hope that helps.